# Venting a bathroom fan to the attic

Tags: attic, vent

I was reading the posts on why it is NOT a good idea to vent a bathroom fan to the attic.  I agree, but is it against most code to do this?  Can someone point me to the code?

Shouldn't the person who was hired to inspect the home before we bought it have noticed this and had the owner fix it?  This was not even noted on his report.

Comment: Sounds like a poor inspector, this is something that is easy to spot and usually caught by inspectors, + Sam for the code.

Answer (score 3):

The Code says it cannot be vented into the attic or crawl space. (See ICC M1507, 2017 edition.)

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot comment on thespecific codes, whether Inspectors notice or report violations or not depends on their skill levels, work experience, and the contracts.  Some contractors may not enter attic or crawlspace if deemed dangerous, even if only a minor possibility of getting scrapes might be present.  Some may not get on top of the roof either, further increasing a chance of overlooking defects or code violations.  These should be found be in the contract you sign with them.  While many inspectors strive for excellence, some do less than adequate job.  Your inspector, if the attic was easily accessible, probably should have noticed it but It's not illegal to have missed something, since it's very difficult to find "everything".  The contract should include a clause about the legal extent of inspectors and how to proceed with a damage claim for the defects (which may or may not be a code violation) found after the purchsse, which the contract might or might state whether the inspector should have discovered it.